# Color tag for accepted answers on "Related" posts

Tags: bug, design, hyperlinks, related-questions

I have a question about a convenient feature that seems to have disappeared after the last "overhaul" (or whatever it was) on M.SE.  I seem to recall that, in the column of "Related" posts associated with the one you are currently viewing, that the numbered box (which appears to indicate question "upvotes", rather than number of answers posted) used to be green if there was an *accepted* answer.

I often look for old posts which have gone unanswered, or have no accepted answers, to see if I might have something useful to contribute (which perhaps I manage to do occasionally).  It made the search more efficient to see that an answer had already been accepted and passing over that one, rather than following a link to a post with a "0" in the box, only to discover that the question has $ \ N \ $ perfectly good answers, none of which were ever accepted (we won't discuss users who "hit-and-run" the site here... :/ ).

Would it be possible to restore that feature?  (I note that it works here on the list of "Questions that may already have your answer".)  Thank you.

Comment: This still happens. The green is a bit faint, but it's there.

Comment: @Pedro I thought I was becoming color-blind, so I checked the source. It appears that for related links with an accepted answer, the little gray box gets a CSS class "answer-accepted" that sets the background-color to dark green. But it get overshadowed by the class "answer-votes" that brings it back to gray. So it's most likely a bug (the classes are not in the right order, answer-accepted should have precedence over answer-votes).